# Salesforce: How to pass id from JavaScript button to Apex class that takes in Set<Id>?

Tags: apex, javascript

on a particular object I have a button that executes JavaScript. Inside of the script I want to call an apex class and pass in the Id of the object I am viewing as a parameter to my apex method but my method takes Set.

My JavasScript Button code looks like below:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}

var parameter = "{!myObject.Id}";

var retVal = sforce.apex.execute( "className", "methodName", {contractIds: parameter});
window.alert(retVal);
window.location.reload();
```

My Apex Class starts off with:

```
public with sharing class className {
  public void methodName(Set<Id> contractIds) {
  ...
  }
}
```

Currently when I press the button I get an error... ***"A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered: {faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:'No operation available for request..."***, how can I properly pass in my parameter? I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is namespace is missing in your code.

Your Code

```
 retVal = sforce.apex.execute( "className", "methodName", {contractIds: parameter});
```

How it should be

```
str = sforce.apex.execute("namespace.AAAParser","parserMethod",{"obj":obj,"NXH":nxh});
```

also your code is that you are passing a single string value as the parameter for your Apex method , but your method expects a Set of Ids
this can help

`var idSet = new Set();`

`idSet.add(parameter);`

Also you can can try including "js" files for different version may be 15.0

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")};
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/apex.js")};

Also try setting your class to **Global**

Some helpful Links,

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005pw7QAA

[Problem with an OnClick JavaScript webservice](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132484/problem-with-an-onclick-javascript-webservice)

Answer (score 0):

[API versions 30.0 and below have been deprecated](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389618&language=en_US&type=1). That's what the error message is telling you. Change the URL to include at least version 31.0.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/apex.js")}
```

I would recommend going up to a more modern version though, as these versions will remain active longer.